# IIS7 ASP.NET MVC 2 Asset Caching Module Not Working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, caching, iis-7, etag

I have this HttpModule that I am using to remove unwanted headers and cache assets for about 30 days but it does not seem to work. Code and http response below:

**Response:**

```
Cache-Control   private
Content-Type    text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Encoding    gzip
Vary    Accept-Encoding
Server  Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNetMvc-Version 2.0
X-AspNet-Version    4.0.30319
X-Powered-By    ASP.NET
Date    Sat, 13 Nov 2010 20:13:57 GMT
Content-Length  1892
```

**Code:**

```
public class AssetCacheModule : IHttpModule
    {
        private static readonly List<string> _headersToRemove = new List<string> { "X-AspNet-Version", "X-AspNetMvc-Version", "Etag", "Server", };   
        private static readonly List<string> _longCacheExtensions = new List<string> {".js", ".css", ".png", ".jpg", ".gif",};  

        public void Init(HttpApplication context)
        {
            context.EndRequest += ContextEndRequest;  
        }

        private static void ContextEndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var context = HttpContext.Current;
            _headersToRemove.ForEach(h => context.Response.Headers.Remove(h));
            var extension = Path.GetExtension(context.Request.Url.AbsolutePath);
            if (_longCacheExtensions.Contains(extension))
            {
                TimeSpan cacheDuration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(44000);
                context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
                context.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.Add(cacheDuration));
                context.Response.Cache.SetMaxAge(cacheDuration);
                context.Response.Cache.AppendCacheExtension("must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate");
            }  
        }
        public void Dispose() { }
    }
```

**web.config:**

```
   <httpModules>
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah"/>
      <add name="CuteWebUI.UploadModule" type="CuteWebUI.UploadModule,CuteWebUI.AjaxUploader"/>
      <add name="AssetCacheModule" type="PostHope.Web.UI.AssetCacheModule, PostHope.Web.UI"/>
    </httpModules>
```

What am I missing???

Comment: +1 for AppendCacheExtension(), which I couldn't find hide nor hair of in the latest MSDN (javadoc-style stubs!) documentation for Response.Cache.  Bless you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're running in Integrated Pipeline mode in IIS7, HTTP modules go under:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
```

Comment: So simple, should have known that! Thanks for taking the time to answer my question.